# VBA Dialogs.Show doesn't display warning message

Tags: vba, excel

Have Excel (2010 in my case but I think it will be the same also in other versions) with two workbooks. Save first one with name "1.xlx" (example) via Save As dialog. Save second one with the same name "1.xlx" to different location. Excel will not allow it with following warning message:

"You cannot save this workbook with the same name as another open workbook or add-in. Choose a different name, or close the other workbook or add-in before saving."

So far so good. But my problem is that I need to invoke dialog via VBA. I am using following code:

```
Sub test()

Application.Dialogs(XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogSaveAs).Show

End Sub
```

Now I am trying to save second workbook (with the same name to different location) but when I click to 'Save' button nothing happen, no warning message. If I wouldn't know what is wrong it would be very difficult to tell. I didn't change any setting (there is nothing as DisplayAlerts set to true or so). Any idea how make SaveAs dialog invoked via VBA to display similar warnings?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why that doesn't give you an error, but it doesn't me either.  If you use Application.FileDialog, you can get that error.

```
Sub testts()

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        .Show
        .Execute
    End With

End Sub
```

Or you could use GetSaveAsFileName and check the names of all the open workbooks and generate the error yourself.

Comment: Maybe this could be a way. But still I would like to know why warning is not displayed.

Comment: My guess is it's a bug, but I hope someone who knows can tell us definitively.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try with the below code on starting on your code.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: It would be great if you can just add a comment what was the issue with the given answer before the answer was voted down.